# Facebook php SDK getUser returns 0 apart from my laptop and the app developer

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

I've looked over hundreds of answers for similar issues to this but can't find anything that seems to help.

I'm running the latest version of the PHP SDK and a login to facebook button which has a generated link from getLoginUrl().

Running on my development laptop and logged in as the application developer it passes me back to the redirect url (Both the callback url when calling getLoginUrl() and the URL set in my application settings are exactly the same) I then do a getUser call which will function in these circumstances.

If i try the same process using my Iphone on the same network, logged in as the same user on facebook getUser() returns 0.
It also does the same for any other user trying to login with facebook.

Sandbox mode is disabled.
my app domains seem to be set up correctly.

I'm really unsure of what to do next.

Comment: When you say "*iphone*", you mean through a browser (mobile web version of the website)? also any code you can share with us?

Comment: I was running it through safari and just using a click through. I'll provide some example code this evening - It's really not far removed from the example code, only it has been abstracted out a few classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks for your responses guys - Turns out the issue was i was sending the request from one page and redirecting back to another. This seems to upset facebook (I'm guessing it will only re-direct back to the page it was called from).
That solved the problem anyway - but many thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are maintaining sessions in your scripts with:

```
session_start();
```

at the top of your php file.

Next use something like this to test if you have a fb user and if not, redirect them to the oauth, which will just renew their token if they've already authorized by it's expired.

```
require_once('facebook/fb.inc');
```

session_start();

```
if (!$fbUser) {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope' => 'email,publish_stream,user_location',
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://scubadivinglog.org/php/fblink.php'
        )
    );
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    exit;
}
```

Hope this helps. Let us know and if not post the code you are using.